# Woocommerce template not working on newly added products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes, templates

My theme templates dynamically create references to images, css classes, etc using the product's name. Pretty standard stuff... but recently, some of this dynamic content stopped working on any new products I add to Woocommerce. Some parts still function, like displaying the name of the product in the header, but others in other cases it fails - like classes being left blank where the product name should appear.

What I can't understand is why everything works fine on any product added prior to a couple weeks ago. It would appear nothing is actually wrong with the templates themselves if they're still displaying older products correctly. Where do I need to look for the source of the problem?

Comment: If you updated the theme it could be an issue with the theme change, if you haven't updated the theme it may be that the manner the theme went about obtaining that information is no longer valid because you perhaps updated WP, WooCommerce or some other plugin.  Ultimately, you should check with the theme developer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.